# ValidateRequest=“false” doesn't work in Asp.Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, .net-framework-version

hi i am getting error : **a potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client.** and my .net version is 4.5, i read some solutions like use **ValidateRequest="false"** on top of page

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

and still its giving error like

**The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

Config Source:

```
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
   <pages>
```

is there any separate **requestValidationMode version for .net 4.5** or what ?? ,what is the solution for it.

Comment: Its is work fine on 4/4.5. Maybe you have some other issue or not readed.

Comment: which one will work fine "<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />" orValidateRequest="false"

Comment: This one you say, together with the `<pages validateRequest="false"`

Comment: this `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` is not going inside the httpruntime

Comment: I'm not really clear on the first half of your question but the error in your second example is fairly straightforward - you can't have *multiple* `httpRuntime` elements. You need to combine the two you have there.

Comment: my first half question is, when i am doing post back call from server button  i am getting that error : **a potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client.** , and i tried putting both but same error in first half is coming